# Selenium sendkeys drops character with Chrome Driver

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Selenium sendkeys with Chrome Driver drops character "2" and "4". Other characters are OK. When I use other browser (IE or FF), everything is OK.

code:

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(localizator);
name.clear();
name.sendKeys("1234567890 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

result: input box is filled with

```
13567890 abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Characters `2` and `4` are missing, other characters are filled correctly.

I use Windows 7 64bit, Chrome version 29.0.1547.57 m, ChromeDriver win32 (v2.2.215849.dyu) - the newest one.

Comment: Have you tried to send the String with many `sendKeys` calls? Is there any difference?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013821/pythons-selenium-send-keys-with-chrome-driver-drops-characters

Comment: I have this issue, but chrome itself will fail to accept a letter- today it's 's'.  Seems to be chrome itself, and so Selenium cannot do anything.  Capital 'S' is accepted.  Very odd behaviour.  Once I close this driver, it will start working again.

Answer (score 9):

Investigating you are from Czech Republic also, I am going to make wild assumption, that your keyboard is set up to Czech as default.

I also had some strange issues with `sendKeys` when my system had Czech keyboard as default one. Since I changed default to English, the problems dissapeared.

If this does not help, please provide info what is going to happen if you try this:

```
  name.sendKeys("2");
  name.sendKeys("22222222");
  name.sendKeys("4");
  name.sendKeys("44444444");
  name.sendKeys("424242");
```

Comment: Same problem with Russian keyboard, I have submitted issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=521

Answer (score 7):

It's an old question but still valid. I use Chrome Driver v2.53.

It looks like the keys are being send one by one to the browser (like a separate keyDown events). When it happens too fast then one of two results can be observable:

- characters are shifted
- characters are missing

My solution is as follows:

```
protected void sendKeys(final WebElement element, final String keys) {
    for (int i = 0; i < keys.length(); i++){
        element.sendKeys(Character.toString(keys.charAt(i)));
        waitUntil(attributeContains(element, "value", keys.substring(0, i)));
    }
}
```

It is reliable and works fast enough. What is more, when we want to clear the input field before sending the keys then the same event shift can occur, e.g:

```
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("abc");
```

It is possible that the clear operation will happen in one of four places:

- before sending the letter "a"
- before sending the letter "b"
- before sending the letter "c"
- after sending the letter "c"

I recommend to always check if the operation we've just executed has been accomplished successfully, e.g.: when we want to clear the input field it's a good practice to:

1. check the value of the input field
2. if the value is an empty string then return
3. if the value is not an empty string then call *clear()* function and wait until the value will be equal to an empty string

It's a lot of operation to execute for a simple task. However, it will make the test more stable.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I ended up calling sendkeys inside a loop until the correct value was inserted. Here's what I did:

```
WebElement name = driver.findElement(By.xpath(...));
this.sendkeys(name,"yourValue");

private void sendkeys(WebElement ele, String val) throws 
InterruptedException
{   ele.clear();
    while(true)
    {   ele.sendKeys(val);
        if(ele.getAttribute("value").equals(val))
            break;
        else
        {   ele.clear();
            Thread.currentThread();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }

    Thread.currentThread();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced this problem when connecting to a VM using VNC and then running the Selenium test that way.

The VNC was actually the one dropping characters. Once I moved to a direct connection to the VM using the VirtualBox console... it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java script to send text. See below code snippet.

```
public void sendTextToFieldWithJS (String str, WebElement element){
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='" + str + "';", element);
}
```