# Protractor - Qwertz - Can not send exclamation mark

Tags: angular, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to write an exclamation mark in an input but Protractor fails at this operation.

What I'm trying to do :

```
element(by.id('nom')).sendKeys('abc!');
```

But I can only see `abc` in my field.

I've added a listener on keyup events, the browser is receiving from Protractor :

```
... keys for 'abc'...
KeyCode : 192 - Code : BackQuote - Key : ~
KeyCode : 16  - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift
```

I kept the window opened (via `browser.pause()`) and I entered an exclamation mark manually, thus I got :

```
KeyCode : 192 - Code : BracketRight - Key : !
KeyCode : 16 - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift
```

I'm using Google Chrome and I have a QWERTZ keyboard.

Does anyone have an idea of why is this happening ?

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616117/7709399

Comment: @M.Hudson I have translated the Java solution of your linl to JavaScript but it's not working. Exclamation mark is still missing. The problem seems to be elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried escaping the ! like `'abc\!'`?

Comment: @JeffC Yes I had. Unfortunately, it was unsuccessful.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i'll keep it in mind for the next time. As for this question, the other things i've tried are in the question.

Comment: When I switch the keyboard to QWERTY, it's working :
`KeyCode : 49 - Code : Digit1 - Key : !
KeyCode : 16 - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift`

Seems to be a bug while using QWERTZ keyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a "solution" that's working but it's weird at the same time.

**Step 1 :** QWERTZ keyboard - Exclamation mark is **not** sent

```
KeyCode : 192 - Code : Backquote - Key : ~
KeyCode : 16 - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift
```

**Step 2 :** QWERTY keyboard (by setting the language at English - USA) - Exclamation mark **is** sent

```
KeyCode : 49 - Code : Digit1 - Key : !
KeyCode : 16 - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift
```

**Step 3 :** QWERTZ keyboard (default language) with language English - USA as second language - Exclamation mark **is** sent

```
KeyCode : 49 - Code : Digit1 - Key : !
KeyCode : 16 - Code : ShiftLeft - Key : Shift
```

This is a - not so pretty - workaround. If someone has a real and proper solution, I'm listening !