# Do double quotes need space inside?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Quite simple, but I'm confused. On my Python script which does web scraping with selenium, all the inputs are

```
input_country = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "country")
input_country.send_keys(" Німеччина ")
time.sleep(5)
```

for country is no space inside needed but when it comes to the input send keys, without space after " it does remove the first letter when writing it to the website.

Does it have any special reason or is it depending on the website?

Sorry for my English I'm still learning.

I tried removing space but it would remove the first letter: example here: `(" Німеччина ")` this works correct, `("Німеччина")` this writes імеччина.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant text based HTML.

Comment: See [this issue](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/3516). AFAIK, there's no workaround now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python's selenium "send\_keys" with chrome driver drops characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013821/pythons-selenium-send-keys-with-chrome-driver-drops-characters)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Chrome.

In that case, this is a common issue. Maybe the answers in [resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013821/pythons-selenium-send-keys-with-chrome-driver-drops-characters).